# Math "sign" error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem, I tried doing simple calculator, when I was almost done and cheered for success, the "sign", which is "znaménko" in Czech (plus, minus, multiple etc., that was what translator gave me) was always plus, even if i selected other. I am total newbie, so please mind that.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated! :)

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

def znamenkoplus():
    znamenko = "+"
    print(znamenko)

def znamenkominus():
    znamenko = "-"
    print(znamenko)

def znamenkokrat():
    znamenko = "."
    print(znamenko)

def znamenkodeleno():
    znamenko = ":"
    print(znamenko)


def rovnase():
    prvnicislo = "%s" % (e1.get())
    druhecislo = "%s" % (e2.get())
    float(prvnicislo)
    float(druhecislo)
    print(prvnicislo)
    print(druhecislo)
    print(znamenko)


    if znamenko == "+":
        cislo1 = float(prvnicislo)
        cislo2 = float(druhecislo)
        vysledek = cislo1 + cislo2
        print (vysledek)
        výsledekLabel.configure(text=vysledek)

    if znamenko == "-":
        cislo1 = float(prvnicislo)
        cislo2 = float(druhecislo)
        vysledek = cislo1 - cislo2
        print(vysledek)
        výsledekLabel.configure(text=vysledek)

    if znamenko == ".":
        cislo1 = float(prvnicislo)
        cislo2 = float(druhecislo)
        vysledek = cislo1 * cislo2
        print(vysledek)
        výsledekLabel.configure(text=vysledek)

    if znamenko == ":":
        cislo1 = float(prvnicislo)
        cislo2 = float(druhecislo)
        vysledek = cislo1 / cislo2
        print(vysledek)
        výsledekLabel.configure(text=vysledek)




master = Tk()


znamenko = "+"
master.title("Kalkulačka")
master.geometry("350x500")

firstLabel = Label(text="Vaše první číslo").place(x=25, y=25)
secondlabel = Label(text="Znaménko").place(x=25, y=75)
thirdlabel = Label(text="Vaše druhé číslo").place(x= 25, y= 125)
výsledekLabel = Label(text="", font=("Helvetica",30))
výsledekLabel.place(x=25, y=350, width=300,height=100)
e1 = Entry()
e2 = Entry()

e1.place(x=130, y=25, width=140)
e2.place(x=130, y=125, width=140)

buttonplus = Button(text="+", command=znamenkoplus).place(x=130, y=75)
buttonminus = Button(text="-", command=znamenkominus).place(x=165, y=75)
buttonkrat = Button(text="・", command=znamenkokrat).place(x=197, y=75)
buttondeleno = Button(text=":", command=znamenkodeleno).place(x=237, y=75)
buttonrovnase = Button(text="=", command=rovnase).place(x=130, y=175, width=140)

mainloop()
```

Comment: It's hard to tell with "nonsensical" variable names. Did you try rubber duck debugging? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: You are probably just missing `global znamenko` in every function. Without it, you are always creating new variables in the functions that shadow the global one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not really a `tkinter` problem, just a basic Python one you have.

You try to set the global variable `znamenko` from inside your functions. That works but only if you use the global keyword.

Try:

```
def znamenkoplus():
    global znamenko
    znamenko = "+"
    print(znamenko)
```

and similar for the other functions that change the variable.

This is one of the reason that `tkinter` apps often have a main class where you can put your state variables, so you can access them via `self` instead of using global everywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly!  I had problems with these, that functions did not recognized variables from other functions, this seems to fix them all. Once more thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

### Variable shadowing

On the line 64, you're setting variable `znamenko` to be defaultly `'+'`:

```
znamenko = "+"
```

Then, in your operator functions, you're trying to set it to the user-define value, e.g. :

```
def znamenkoplus():
    znamenko = "+"
    print(znamenko)
```

This works, however, *not* the way you meant. It changes value of the variable `znamenko` *inside the function*. 
Beware, this is not the variable `znamenko` from the line 64. This is a *different variable* with completely *different location*, with the same name. When this leaves scope, `znamenko` from inside the function is freed - and the global variable `znamenko` is left untouched (that's why it is always `'+'`). This is called **variable shadowing**.

Try this:

```
def znamenkominus():
    znamenko = "-"
    print("Znamenko in the function", znamenko)

znamenko = "+"

print("Znamenko before change", znamenko)

znamenkominus()

print("Znamenko after change", znamenko)
```

`znamenko` will have the same value as it had before the change.

### Changing global variable from a function

You can change global variable by adding `global znamenko`:

```
def znamenkominus():
    global znamenko
    znamenko = "-"
    print("Znamenko in the function", znamenko)

znamenko = "+"

print("Znamenko before change", znamenko)

znamenkominus()

print("Znamenko after change", znamenko)
```

This will change the global variable (and won't create any local variable)